# Have element change select form value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I link the actions of a click function to a select form with jquery.

For exmaple if an image 1 is clicked. How can I let the form know that image 1 is clicked by changing the 'selected' option in a form.

```
<a href="#" rel="green">Green</a>
<select>
 <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

When "green" is clicked the "selected" option is added to the selection

I know i've seen it done before. I just cannot find it anywhere.

Thanks, 
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('select').val($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MZ7nS/

Comment: Won't both of these hijack every link on the page and not just the ones he wants to work with?

Comment: @Silvertiger just using the OP's example to keep it simple. But, yes, both GregL and this one will do that.

Comment: this is it :O i used green because it was easy to describe but I actually have numbers so the value and the rel in the href are equal. Amazing. thank you. I didn't think it would be this simple :D

Answer (score 1):

a bit if javascript magic and you're in business

```
<a href="#" rel="green" onClick="document.getElementById('colorselect').value = 'green';">Green</a>
<select id="colorselect">
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute selector to find the option with the corresponding value:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('select').find('option[value=' + optionValue + ']').prop('selected', true);
});
```